# Variable string inside variable name

Tags: python, string, loops, variables

I know this is a bad title, and I realize that dictionaries are usually the way to solve this, but I'm not sure how they would solve the issue in my particular case.

I am using `argsparse` to collect inputs from the user. Two of the variables we'll call `args.session_1` and `args.session_2` which refer to paths.

Later in my script, I iterate through sessions 1 and 2, and I also need to iterate through the directories referred to by the `args.session_{ }` paths. However, I'm not sure how to do the latter.

I typically use f-strings, for example, but it wouldn't work like this:

```
for session in [1, 2]:
    for file in os.listdir(f'args.session_{session}'):
        do whatever
```

Here, `args.session_1` is a string, not a variable name, so this doesn't work. My question is, how can I have `args.session_{ }` still be a variable name but also have the session itself a variable?

Would this require using a dict? I wasn't sure how that would help since the dictionary value would have the same issue of being a string.

Comment: what do you get if you `print(args.session_1)`, and `session_2`?

Comment: They are strings. Please see @Barmar's answer, which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getattr()` to access attributes dynamically.

```
for session in [1, 2]:
    for file in os.listdir(getattr(args, 'session_' + session)):
        # do whatever
```